# resize ngFor iterated images but keep their relation to each other in tact

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working on an image row where I iterate over differently sized images.
My basic idea is to ngFor over an array of (asset) URLs, so I'm currently doing something like this:

```
<div>    
  <img class="preview-image-small" *ngFor="let unit of array" [src]="getAssetUrl(unit)">
</div>
```

Without any styling, it produces exactly what I want, just way too big. How can I resize all images but keep their original ratio. Is there a way to 'change the viewport' of the wrapping div so that it resembles the 3rd row of my stackblitz example?

A css version would be preferred, I hope to avoid the tedious way of analyzing the image sizes and calculating the smallest based on the tallest in js.

[image: stackblitz screenshot]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skzcsz?file=src/main.ts

Comment: you can add  `max-height` as long as you don't set  the width it will keep it's orginal ratio.

Comment: I gave up and brute forced it. Would still be happy to see a css only solution. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at9snh?file=src/main.ts
Beats me why I can't set my height in percent as soon as I `align-items: flex-end` it just stops working if you don't specify height in pixel from there on..

@Nathan sry I didn't understand what you were going for. I don't want to keep my ratio in one image, but across multiple images, scaling them all based on the largest biggest